# Emailing a link to run .exe file with an argument

Tags: arguments, dos, exe

Does anyone knows how I can email a link to an executable file(.exe) with an argument. So when the recipient clicks the link, the .exe file opens with specific record.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a windows shorcut file (.lnk) by right clicking on the exe -> Create Shortcut
2. Right click on the shortcut -> Properties -> Edit the target by adding your arguments
3. Email your "virus" to the poor recipient :-)

Be aware that it may be possible for email servers to flag the attachment as suspicious. You should probably zip it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo I turned echo off because it looks ugly, but try deleting that line.
echo.
echo Let's look at your files...
dir
echo Now let's open notepad and look at our own source code!
notepad example.bat
```